# Problema con apariencia de mi aplicación

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, android-layout

Tengo un problema con mi aplicacion, ya que cuando estoy ordenando los componentes en Android Studio, los ordeno como quiero que se vean, sin embargo, cuando ejecuto la app en mi celular, los controles se ven completamente desordenados, he probado usar el relativelayout y el constraintLayout, pero ninguno de los 2 me ha funcionado, aqui dejo mi codigo XML,  espero que me puedan ayudar.

````
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/scene">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="329dp"
        android:layout_height="366dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.621"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/manzana" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fondoet"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/et_nombre"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.333"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fondoboton2"
        android:text="@string/btnjugar"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="142dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fondoet"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout> ```
````

Comment: estas usando android studio para desarrollar dicha aplicacion? si es asi muestrame el editor de diseño

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer el ultimo TextView tenia el Topconstraint mal puesto, al parecer se solucionara tu problema al cambiar el código xml de tu textView, quedando así:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoet"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Incluyendo algunas correcciones para un mejor diseño de tu layout quedria asi:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/scene">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="329dp"
    android:layout_height="366dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.621"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/manzana" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoet"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/et_nombre"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.333"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoboton2"
    android:text="@string/btnjugar"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoet"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

espero y te funcione :)